# When deploying through Azure DevOps getting error: You do not have permission to view this directory or page

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, devops

When I am deploying the web application using DevOps pipeline I am getting this error: "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." I figured out that when I deploy it manually with the "publish" button there is no initial folder in uploaded files, but when uploaded through Azure DevOps there are initial folders with all the projects, any ideas?

files structure when deployed from "publish" button directly from VS (working) [image: link]

files structure when deployed from Azure DevOps (not working) [image: link]

the error: You do not have permission to view this directory or page [image: link]

when open swagger UI: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed or is temporarily unavailable. [image: link]

azure-pipelines.yaml file :

```
    trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019
  demands: npm

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'angular-cli'
  inputs:
    workingDir: src/Kronova.MovingPortal.Web.Host
    verbose: false

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'ng build'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: src/Kronova.MovingPortal.Web.Host
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run publish-full'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: dist'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: src/Kronova.MovingPortal.Web.Host/wwwroot
    ArtifactName: dist

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET SDK 3.1'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '3.1.x'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Restore project dependencies'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build the project - $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '--no-restore --configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    projects: |
      **/*.csproj
      !**/*Mobile*.csproj
      !**/*Client*.csproj
      !**Kronova.MovingPortal.Application.Client/**

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish the project - $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    projects: |
      **/*.csproj
      !**/*Mobile*.csproj
      !**/*Client*.csproj
      !**Kronova.MovingPortal.Application.Client/**'
    publishWebProjects: false
    arguments: '--no-build --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)'
    zipAfterPublish: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Estimated_Pad_Api'
  condition: succeeded()
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'Estimated_Pad_Api'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: Please put relevant information in the question instead of links.

Comment: @Crowcoder What you mean with relevant? I think the problem is quite enough described to be understood, if not then please tell me what information do you need more so I can give it to you :).

Comment: If the stuff at the links is relevant, then put it directly in the question. It is poor etiquette to ask us to treasure hunt the Internet to understand the problem. And code and messages are text, not images so it is also advisable to paste as text instead of providing screenshots.

Comment: Test with the similar `dotnet build` process. It will generate a file structure similar to that in vs(e.g. .dll json pdb files). From the yaml file, I notice that you publish two artifacts files. You could check if the artifacts content is correct. Then when you use the artifacts to publish to web app, you need to make sure that you select the correct artifacts folder.